# jQuery Counter Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

JavaScript/jQuery newbie here!

I have the following form here (using bootstrap's disabled class, heads up):

EDIT: the class 'disabled' is a thing in bootstrap, and does properly disable and enable the button if it is there or not.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" id="bio">
<p class="bio-counter"></p>
<input type="text" id="username">
<p class="user-counter"></p>
<input type="submit" class="btn">
</form>
```

And the following script (I have included jQuery in my head tag correctly):

```
var main = function() {
   $('.bio-counter').text('500');
   $('.user-counter').text('0');
   var postLengthUser = $('#username').val().length;
   var postLengthBio = $('#bio').val().length;
   $('#username').keyup(function() {
     $('.user-counter').text(postLengthUser);
   });
   $('#bio').keyup(function() {
    var charactersLeftBio = 500 - postLengthBio;
    $('.bio-counter').text(charactersLeftBio);
  });
  if(postLengthUser > 6 && postLengthUser < 21) {
    if(postLengthBio >= 0 && postLengthBio < 501) {
      $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
      $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
    }
  } else {
    $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
  }
}

$(document).ready(main);
```

I am running into the following problems:

- The 'btn' is not losing it's disabled state, even when I type enough information in the inputs.
- The counters are not updating.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try putting the function inside the $(document).ready(function( instead of calling it in a variable

Comment: you dont use removeClass and AddClass for property

Comment: @Markipe The class 'disabled' is a thing in bootstrap, and does properly disable and enable the button if it is there or not.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad That didn't work. To my knowledge, it doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    var main = function () {
        var postLengthUser = 0;
        var postLengthBio = 0;

        $('.bio-counter').text(500);
        $('.user-counter').text(0);


        var validate = function () {
            if (postLengthUser > 6 && postLengthUser < 21) {
                if (postLengthBio >= 0 && postLengthBio < 501) {
                    $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
                }
            } else {
                $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
            }
        }

        $('#username').keyup(function () {
            postLengthUser = $('#username').val().length;
            $('.user-counter').text(postLengthUser);

            validate();
        });

        $('#bio').keyup(function () {
            postLengthBio = $('#bio').val().length;
            var charactersLeftBio = 500 - postLengthBio;
            $('.bio-counter').text(charactersLeftBio);

            validate();
        });

        validate();
    }

    $(document).ready(main);
</script>
```

1. You're validating the disabled condition only at page load, it should be run at each keyup event - i moved it to validate function.
2. postLengthUser and postLengthBio were updated only at page load too. They should be updated on each key up event too.

Comment: This doesn't work, but I think it may be because of variable scoping problems.

Comment: I ran this code and it seems to be working fine for me. Did you copy-paste this or try to fix your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
```

and

```
$('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
```

instead.

Comment: Not working, the same problems are still happening. Thank you for the suggestion, though. :)